Tailwind CSS Problem with white-space not being applied
I'm currently using Tailwind CSS v3.4.10 and trying to use the whitespace: pre-line style property.
<p className="whitespace-pre-line"> 
  Hello\n
  hi
  good
</p>

I'm using it like this, but it doesn't work. It appears in one line.
I would like to know how to test or solve this problem.
I applied whitespace: pre-line as regular CSS in other projects, but it didn't work.
I tried applying white-space in another project, but it didn't work either.

Is this in React? Try Hello{'\n'}.

Do I have to do that in JSX?

@Dogbert
In HTML, does it apply even if I just change the line?

You wrote className so I assumed it's JSX/React. If it's plain HTML it should be class="...".

Include in your question which version of Tailwind are you using

@Dogbert Should I use Hello{'\n'} in JSX?   Can't I just do a line break? Hello    world Like this

@vsync
The version is "tailwindcss": "^3.4.10"

@Hees yes, you need to use {'\n'}. Newlines outside of that are converted to spaces in JSX.

Solution with React syntax
I think the syntax that might have confused you is related to React. In React's syntax, we avoid using the default class attribute. Instead, a className attribute was introduced, which works as you described in your question.
I would also like to note that in Babel, text in <pre> tags is passed with \n for line breaks, as shown in the example.

className global attribute in React DOM - React Docs
When did React start supporting class attribute in JSX - StackOverflow answer
How to automatically do line break in <pre> tag? - StackOverflow answer



// App component
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Successfully with "className" attribute */}
      <p className="whitespace-pre-line">
        {'Hello\nhi\ngood'}
      </p>
      {/* or */}
      <p className="whitespace-pre-line">
        Hello{'\n'}
        hi{'\n'}
        good{'\n'}
      </p>

      {/* Successfully with "class" attribute. However, the class attribute is not part of the JSX syntax, and its use is not recommended. */}
      <p class="whitespace-pre-line">
        {'Hello\nhi\ngood'}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render the application to the DOM
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



Solution with native HTML
I added the React tag to the question, so I will also leave the HTML-based answer here.
In native HTML, there is no className attribute. The default attribute for assigning CSS classes to an element is called class.

class global attribute - MDN Docs



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<!-- Don't work with "className" attribute -->
<p className="whitespace-pre-line">
  Hello
  hi
  good
</p>

<!-- Successfully with "class" attribute -->
<p class="whitespace-pre-line">
  Hello
  hi
  good
</p>



